# How should I call my JavaScript. href, onclick or bind the click event?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I know there are already a lot of articles about this concept but my question has a little difference.

On my page, I have a link:

```
<a id="mylink">click me </a>
```

Then I'm changing the href dynamically using:

```
$get('mylink').href = 'javascript:doSomething(id);';
```

It happens I have to call the above code multiple times so I overwrite the current value of the href attribute with JavaScript code calling the same function with different id parameter.

The above is what I'm using for a long time now, but the mess started some time ago when I'm trying to implement `OnNavigateAway` to warn the user when they closes the browser window. IE will also trigger this `onNavigateAway` event when the user clicks a anchor with a value for the href attribute.

So I started to replace those href's with jQuery click events:

```
$("#mylink").click(function (e) {
doSomething(id);
e.preventDefault();
});
```

But remember that this code can be called multiple times, so I have to unbind the click event first and then bind again:

```
function completed(result) { 
$("#mylink").unbind('click'); 
    $("#mylink").click(function (e) {
    doSomething(result.id);
    e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Is this a good way to handle my JavaScript? Or is this binding and unbind stuff no good practice?

Another way to do this can be to overwrite the `onclick` attribute manually with JavaScript.

How would you handle this?

I'm looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use different logic here. Instead of reassigning the click event, I will just change some data property then in the "global" click event use this property:

```
$("#mylink").on("click", function (e) {
    doSomething($(this).data("id"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then when you need to change that `id` have such code:

```
$("#mylink").data("id", id);
```

This way repeated calls to change the data will cause only the last to affect e.g.

```
$("#mylink").data("id", 5);
$("#mylink").data("id", 6);
$("#mylink").data("id", 7);
```

When clicked, 7 will be passed to the function.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/EQ4Dt/).

In case the element is created dynamically and assuming you're using jQuery 1.7 or above you can use the `.on` to catch even those dynamically created elements:

```
$("body").on("click", "#mylink", function (e) {
    doSomething($(this).data("id"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I get what you mean, but should i check if the click event has been binded yet? If not, bind the click event like you do?

Comment: @ThdK wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function() {...})` you should have no problem - unless the link is created dynamically somehow?

Comment: It is created dynamically. I've updated my question a bit, so you see there is a function being called passing the response parameter. Response is an object containing an id attribute.

Comment: @ThdK see my edit. Still no need to check if already binded, the new form is equivalent to the old `.live()` mechanism of jQuery

Comment: thanks for keep on trying. Unfortunately, I'm still using jquery 1.5.

Comment: @ThdK no worry, just change to `$("#mylink").live("click", function (e) {` and it should still work. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQ4Dt/1/).